# XML document default namespace

Tags: xml

A friend showed me the following XML doc and asked me some questions. I'd like to check them with you

For the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<product xmlns:m="urn:example.com:catalog">
    <m:productInfo>
        <detail xmlns="urn:example.com:products">
            <name>Hello World!</name>
        </detail>
    </m:productInfo>
</product>
```

What is the URI of the namespace to which the top level `<product>` element belongs?
What is the URI of the namespace to which the `<productInfo>` element belongs?

Thanks!

Comment: Will your "friend" also be awarding you marks based on how you answer these questions?

Comment: LOL. On the absence of reputation points I will be accepting money... or beer.

Comment: Here's another 2 - what namespace is `detail` in, and what namespace is element `name` in?

Comment: Do you want me to add those to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product` is in the [`no namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) (sometimes informally called *global* namespace), since, although it defines the namespace alias `xmlns:m="urn:example.com:catalog"`, `product` itself is not in this namespace.

Product would only be in namespace `urn:example.com:catalog` if it was declared either:

```
<m:product xmlns:m="urn:example.com:catalog">
```

or if it reset the default namespace:

```
<product xmlns="urn:example.com:catalog">
```

`productInfo` IS in namespace `urn:example.com:catalog`, for the reason above.

Detail resets the default namespace:

```
<detail xmlns="urn:example.com:products">
```

Which means that `detail`, and sub-elements (such as `name`) are also in namespace `urn:example.com:products`